# No file upload, but a broken image is shown

Tags: php, database, image, file-upload

I have got a form with a file upload and I would like to have no file(image) should be shown, when no file is selected. I always get an broken image, because the script is writing an image path in my data base. But i do not want show an image, when no file(image) is selected.

Here is my php code:

```
$info_messages  =   array();
$filename       =   '';

// Wenn es kein Odner "user_pic" gibt, dann wird einer erstellt
    if( !is_dir( 'user_pics' ) ){

        mkdir( 'user_pics' );

    }

    // Sicherstellen, dass nur Bilder vom Typ JPG hochgeladen wurden
    if( isset( $_FILES['w_pic']['type'] ) != 'image/jpeg' ){

        $info_messages[] =  'Format des Fotos muss "JPG" sein!';

    }


    if (  $_FILES['w_pic']['size'] > 0 ) {

        list( $width, $height ) = getimagesize( $_FILES['w_pic']['tmp_name'] ); 

        // Überprüfen, dass das Bild nicht größer als "360x280" Pixel groß ist
        if( $height > 360 || $width > 280 ){ 

            $info_messages[] = "Das Bild darf maximal \"360\" Pixel hoch und \"280\" Pixel breit sein!";

        }

    }


    // Wenn es Fehler gibt, dann werden sie ausgegeben, ansonsten führe die SQL-Query aus
    if ( count( $info_messages ) > 0 ) {

        echo "<div id='workerform'><h3>Folgende Fehler sind aufgetreten</h3></div>" . implode( "<br>", $info_messages );


    } else {

        // nutzen der Do-While Schleife zum erzeugen eines eindeutigen neuen Dateinamens für die hochgeladenen Datei
        do{

            $filename   =   md5( uniqid() . $_FILES['w_pic']['name']) . ".jpg";

        } while( file_exists( 'user_pics/'.$filename ) );

        // verschiebt eine Datei aus dem TMP-Upload Verzeichnis ins Zielverzeichnis
        move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['w_pic']['tmp_name'], 'user_pics/'.$filename );
```

and my HTML code:

```
<p>
<?php if (!is_null($value['w_pic'])) : ?>
<img src="<?= $value['w_pic'] ?>">
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I Believe php's `is_null` doesn't return false if an empty string is checked. I think the safest way to go is
`if (isset($value['w_pic']) && $value['w_pic'])`
What this does is, making sure the array key exist, and if the value contains anything

Comment: Just use !empty($value['w_pic']). The isset check is also done by empty()

Comment: I guess, my problem is, that the file is not empty. he is always writing a file name(path) in my database. Here is an screenshot [link]http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3818/zgpph4q5_jpg.htm

Comment: if i do a print_r($_FILES) of an empty file, i have got this:

Array ( [w_pic] => Array ( [name] => [type] => [tmp_name] => [error] => 4 [size] => 0 ) )

I tought wrong, it is the error message for: UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE
Value: 4; No file was uploaded. But why is he writing a non existing path in my databse? :D